# BitConverter destination array is not long enough to copy all the items in the collection

Tags: c#

I try to convert my `ascii` encoded value into bits using `BitConverter.ToInt32`. I do not understand why i am getting below error. `a` after conversion has *6 bytes* and `b` *2 bytes*. There is no issue with `a` but it is with `b`. Can u explain me why is that and what's wrong?

**Error thrown on this line:**

```
var bb = BitConverter.ToInt32(bb, 0);
```

**Error:**

> „System.ArgumentException” w System.Private.CoreLib.dll: 'Destination
> array is not long enough to copy all the items in the collection.
> Check array index and length.'

**Full code:**

```
var a = EncodeStringToAscii("connId", Encoding.ASCII, 1023);
var b = EncodeStringToAscii("to", Encoding.ASCII, 1023);

var aa = BitConverter.ToInt32(a, 0);
var bb = BitConverter.ToInt32(b, 0);


public byte[] EncodeStringToAscii(string value, Encoding encoding, int maxBytesLimit = 0)
{
     Encoding enc = encoding;
     byte[] bytes = enc.GetBytes(value);

     if (maxBytesLimit != 0)
         if (bytes > maxBytesLimit)
             throw new Exception($"String has {bytes} of bytes and the limit is {maxBytesLimit}");

     return bytes;
}
```

Comment: Based on the documentation BitConverter.ToInt32 expects 4 bytes else it will throw. You could use ToInt16 for b

Comment: `"connId"` is too long (`6` bytes) be turned into `int32` (`4` bytes)

Comment: BitConverter.ToInt32 expects an array of at least 4 bytes. If you pass an array of 6 bytes it will use only the first 4, but if you pass an array of 2 bytes it will throw.

Comment: @Alberto so simply speaking BitConverter.ToInt32 (with starting point 0) will cut everything after 4th byte? Which means if `connId` has `6 bytes` only the first `4 bytes` will be returned and kept to the `aa` and last `2 bytes` will be removed. For `to` as it's `2 bytes` it will throw as u said because its not enough. Is that understanding correct?

Comment: @Arie yes, exactly.

Answer (score 0):

Well, `BitConverter.ToInt32` wants *exactly* `4` bytes array to convert it into `int`. If we have a *smaller* array, we can `Resize` it; in case of larger array, let's throw an exception.

Code:

```
public static int EncodeStringToInt32(string value, Encoding? encoding = default) {
  if (value is null)
    throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(value));

  encoding ??= Encoding.Default;

  byte[] bytes = encoding.GetBytes(value);

  if (bytes.Length > sizeof(int))
    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(value), 
      $"{value} is too long to be converted into int.");

  if (bytes.Length < sizeof(int))
    Array.Resize(ref bytes, sizeof(int));

  return BitConverter.ToInt32(bytes);
}
```

Demo:

```
int result = EncodeStringToInt32("to");

Console.Write(result);
```

Output:

```
28532
```

Comment: What do you mean by `Resize` ? If we have `2 bytes` when `4` are expected is that mean that `Array.Resize` just willl fill the missing `2 bytes` by adding `sixteen zeros` at the beggining (2 leading bytes) or?

Comment: @Arie: Actually, `Array.Resize` takes an existing array and if `Length` and required size are not equal creates a *new* array of required size, copy existing array into a new one and return created array by reference. If we have `2` bytes then an array of `4` bytes will be created with initial `2` bytes being copied into it.

Comment: `BitConverter.ToInt32` does not require exactly 4 byte array, you can pass an index https://dotnetfiddle.net/7TrLaD

Comment: @Charlieface: Your are quite right, thank for your comment.  We can provide a *longer* array and specify the index from where to start reading `4` bytes. In the question, however, in case of longer array we should throw an exception: I can't see any reasonable index to use; in case of shorter array `Resize` (or its emulation) seems to be inevitable.